# Weird back arrow on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I was given a picture of how the navigation arrow back button look like on specific devices (iPhone SE, 5) and I have no clue what might cause this issue.

[image]

It should be standard back arrow icon instead. I was not able to reproduce it on simulators and I am wondering if someone can encounter with same bug.

Comment: It looks as if the user has switched on `Enable Button Shapes` in `Accessibility`: http://osxdaily.com/2014/06/25/enable-button-shapes-ios/

Comment: Omg... Thanks for the help